# Delayer transaction management

Tags: spring-integration

I want to make sure the Delayer tied to a PersistentMessageStore will rollback to the DB if there was an exception proceeding from the Delayer after the delay time.
Will the transactional attribute take care of this or I need to have a txAdvice?

```
 <int:delayer id="abcDelayer" 
            default-delay="1000"
            message-store="JDBCMessageStore">
     <int:transactional/>
 </int:delayer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#delayer-message-store):

> The `<delayer>` can be enriched with mutually exclusive sub-elements `<transactional>` or `<advice-chain>`. The List of these AOP Advices is applied to the proxied internal `DelayHandler.ReleaseMessageHandler`, which has the responsibility to release the `Message`, after the delay, on a `Thread` of the scheduled task. It might be used, for example, when the downstream message flow throws an `Exception` and the `ReleaseMessageHandler`'s transaction will be rolled back. In this case the delayed `Message` will remain in the persistent `MessageStore`.